# Saving Image to Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, save-image

I am working on the user profile screen for one of my apps. I wanted to allow the user to select an image from his phone and be able to see his profile image in the main screen of the application. The problem I have is that an image takes longer to save than plain text. I would like to find a way to make sure the image is saved to parse before the segue takes the user to the main screen. Right now as soon as I click next, the segue takes the user to the main screen. In the main screen the user's profile image is not able to display because the profile image that was "saved" to parse is empty. When this happens i get a nil value exception.

**Note:** When i remove the Segue - the application successfully saves the user's info and the user's image.

the following code is after I do all my checks on username, password etc.

```
        if photoSelected == false {
        error = "Please select an image to post"
        }

        if error != "" {
        displayAlert("Cannot Post Image", error: error)

        } else {

        var post = PFObject(className: "Images")
        post["username"] = PFUser.currentUser().username

  post.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if success == false {
        self.displayAlert("Could not post Image", error: "Please try again later")

        } else {
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.profileImage.image)
        let profilePic = PFFile(name: "image.png", data: imageData)

        post["profileImage"] = profilePic;

            //I even added an activity indicator to stall the app before proceeding to the main page. 
            activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200))
            activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
            activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
            self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()


        post.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in


            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

        if success == false {
        self.displayAlert("Could not post Image", error: "Please try again later")
        } else {
         //check    
        println("picture was uploaded")

        }
        })

       }
    })
  }


        //saves all the user's values username, password, etc. 
        self.user.save()

     //takes the user to the MainScreen     
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("moveToMainScreen", sender: self)

    }
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move these lines:

```
 //takes the user to the MainScreen     
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("moveToMainScreen", sender: self)
```

higher up, into the completion block for the image save (where you have `println("picture was uploaded")` now.